# how to add decoratives in select box in zend framework Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am new to zend I want to add decoratives,size in my select box

example like this

'required'   => true,

'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),

'style'    => array('width:103px'),
'multiOptions' => $list,

'decorators'=>Array(

```
'ViewHelper','Errors'
       ),
```

this is my code

$companyName = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('companyName');
$this->addElement($companyName);

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but you can supply an array of options as the second parameter to the form element:

```
$companyName = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('companyName', array(
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array('StringTrim')
));
$this->addElement($companyName);
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will help you

http://www.codexperience.co.za/post/creating-good-looking-zend-forms

Its all about styling your zend forms using the traditional way whilst retaining the awesomeness that `Zend_Form` comes with